# ActionBar menuitem pressed background color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-styles

I made an action bar with ActionBarSherlock. I want to style the action bar so when i press a menuitem (a drop down item which pops up from the overflow), the menuitem background should change color. (Now it changes to the default holo blue, i want it to be another color).

After long googleing and testing, a came up with this:

`themes.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Holo.Theme">

    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/menu_selector</item>
</style>
```

`menu_selector.xml`: (like `abs__list_selector_holo_dark.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_disabled_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_disabled_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/AppRed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/AppRed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_focused_holo" />
    <item                                                              android:drawable="@color/AppRed" />
</selector>
```

Unfortunately, the background still changes to blue instead of red.
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will generate ActionBar styles for you, you can choose to only change the accent color which will modify the action bar item selector (you'll still have to copy all the files it generates to your project though):

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/